# Paytrace payment in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, invoice, payment-gateway, paytrace

I have used paytrace extension from [gitlab public repo](https://gitlab.com/bfellows/magento-paytrace) but having issue while creating invoice. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Kindly take a look at gitlab repo and assist how can I create invoice for this.
Thanks.

Comment: anything in log? seems like issue with validation

Comment: the link that you have shared have following lines in its readme file "This is a magento Module I wrote to easily add a save-my-card feature to a Magento site using PayTrace.
It is not functional as is, you would need a service for the customer to save and retreive tokens (search repo for "my.service.url")."

Comment: @promod, thanks I will check If can found this url, As the repo seems override the authorized.net files